# FSCalendar date not aligned properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fscalendar

When I first load my calendar, the layout become misaligned (refer to image 1). After physically rotating my device to landscape and back to portrait, it fix itself. (refer to image 2)

Anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? I do not know where to start to find the issue that caused this to happen.

Side note: (not sure if this have anything to do with the issue.)

- the page before this also have another FSCalendar.
- this affected fscalendar is inside a scrollview with constraint set to height = 0.4 of superview, width with left right margin of 8, and center x align to superview.

[image: First load]

[image: After device rotate]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (and just like for you, rotating the device would fix it).

I was able to fix my problem by changing the layout constraints and setting the FSCalendar's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` (I had created the FSCalendar programmatically).

In the end, I put the FSCalendar inside another UIView and set it up like this:

```
calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
calendarContainer.addSubview(calendarView)
[NSLayoutConstraint(item: calendarView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: calendarContainer, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: calendarView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: calendarContainer, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: calendarView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: calendarContainer, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: calendarView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: calendarContainer, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
].forEach({ $0.isActive = true })
```

Comment: What is `previousButton`?

Comment: @Jalil Oh, that was just another view in the container. I've now removed it for simplicity.

Comment: You can use NSLayoutConstraint.activate([]) instead of forEach()